# Duplicate Key Error in NodeJS app

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

```
E11000 duplicate key error collection: 59d6ca84c0c6e3427c72b983_policy-api-xyz-alpha.people index: displayId_1 dup key: { : null }"}]}
```

We get this error always after a `yield mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase();` in our nodeJS app. We are connecting to MongoDB Atlas Cloud ReplicaSet. Any idea how to debug?

Comment: seems this is some funny business by mongoose have you considered ignoring the error within a catch block

Comment: We could do that.... I think the issue is more complicated though.

Comment: You mean you are running unit tests when you see this don't you? If you are dropping the database then you actually appear to have something recreating indexes as well. Because dropping the database gets rid of everything. And the error says there is an index on `displayId` in the collection. So there is code re-creating that index.

Comment: Yes it's test that call the dropDatabase. So it would be better to iterate through the collections and remove them one by one and keep old indexes instead of using dropDB?

Comment: @nottinhill Can you maybe show some code that reproduces this in the smallest possible listing then please. And also please use the `@` thingy to notify those who comment that you responded. Otherwise we only see it when we eventually browse to and open your question, as opposed to being notified.

Comment: Unfortunately the code is huge. I will need days to break down the issue. What happens is a dropDB like said and the testers are fast, so there might be replication issues ?! We solved this in the past by also restarting the entire NodeJS application.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem and solved it by running:

```
User.collection.dropAllIndexes(function (err, results) {});
```